# Debit Credit Balance and opening Balance Calculation

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have Sql database with following columns:

- AcccountName
- Debit
- Credit
- DR/CR

I set date range and account name criteria to generate the crystal report.

For example, if i select two date ranges from dtpickers and account name "CASH" from combobox present in crystal report form. it will generate me all cash transactions within selected date range.

What I want is while generating crystal report with one more columns containing running balance.
what I have tried so far in formula field:

**For debit credit calculation:**

```
global numbervar Balance;
balance = 0;
if {Transactionss.DR/CR} = "DR" then
balance := balance +{Transactionss.Debit}-{Transactionss.Credit}
else  
balance := balance+{Transactionss.Credit}-{Transactionss.Debit}
```

But it is not working. Moreover i also want to bring previous balance and connect this opening balance with this debit credit calculation.

Sample image:

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Where is your SQL query? you can add running balance column within SQL query itself.

Comment: I can not do it in sql because there are diffrent account names. I need it it in Crystal report with particular account name i select through combobox.

Comment: Your code says `"DR"` and your pictures says `1`

Comment: Quite many SQL databases are capable of calculating running totals per account name without any problems.

Comment: I am sorry it should be Dr i forget to change before taking screen shot. But i am a learner. Could u pls explain the query here to get running total with date and account name critera sql database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a running total field.

But if you want to continue in this way, I think you are having trouble with null values. So, try something like this:

```
global numbervar balance;
numbervar debit := 0;
numbervar credit := 0;
if not isnull({Transactionss.Debit}) then debit := {Transactionss.Debit};
if not isnull({Transactionss.Credit}) then credit := {Transactionss.Credit};
if {Transactionss.DR/CR} = "DR" then
  balance := balance + debit - credit
else  
  balance := balance + credit - debit
```

It may have some mistake, because I can't test this formula right now.

It may be necessary to start the balance variable somewhere before, because it's initial value may be is unknown. For example, put the following formula in report header.

```
global numbervar balance;
balance : = 0;
```

Comment: heringer Thanks very much for your response. you have solve my issue. i am posting this code below in case it can help anyone else.                                                                  global numbervar Bal;
bal = 0;
numbervar Debit :=0;
numbervar Credit :=0;
if not isnull ({Transactionss.Debit}) then debit:={Transactionss.Debit};
if not isnull ({Transactionss.Credit}) then credit:={Transactionss.Credit};
if {Transactionss.DRCR} = "DR" then

bal :=bal+debit-credit

Comment: heringer, would you please explain explain the formula to get te openning balance from the table and show in crystal report.

Comment: This new question is too broad. I don't know the context. You may try to sum credits and debits before the start date. But there are a lot of details there. You problably want to do it by account. You may have performance issues. You may have accounts the reverses the signal. I cannot help you on that, sorry.